# Concurrent SaveChanges with several entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

In my asp.net core application I have a background service that periodically goes through the DB and updates some entities.

```
public class Entity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int State { get; set; }
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var entity in database.Entities)
                UpdateState(entity);

            database.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            // Yes, well, that's kinda expected
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Just in case
        }
        await Task.Delay(10 * 1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that we have several instances of the application working with the same DB, so I wonder what will happen if two instances will try to update the DB simultaneously. Can it be guaranteed that at least one of the two requests will succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of the requests will always succeed, namely the first in. The way concurrency checks work is that EF adds a where clause to the update statement specifying something like:

```
WHERE State = 3
```

Where the value is what EF last knew about. If another instance of the context successfully updated the entity, such that `State` is now 4, for example, then the update statement fails to match anything, and EF throws the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. If value does match, then the update goes through as expected.

As such, your catch block should implement a recovery strategy. Generally, that's going to be getting the latest values from the database, and then attempt to remodify the entity from there, before attempting to update again. The various strategies you can employ, as well as how to achieve each, are well-covered in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I more or less understand how ConcurrencyCheck works, but what I do not understand, is how it works with several entities at once. I do not quite understand how transactions are implemented inside EF, and what will happen if two instances will make SaveChanges exactly at the same time.

Comment: Transactions work as they always do. It's all or nothing. Any part fails, everything rolls back. What will happen if two instances save at the same time is concurrency and everything described above. There is no *exactly* the same time. One will always beat the other if only by milliseconds. First in locks the row and makes the update. Second is queued at database.